# Better Way of Dealing With Circular References? - EF Core 3.1 and Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I am currently trying to progress with EF Core with a one-to-many (a `user` has many `items`).  A tutorial or three later I managed to get things working with two very small and simple tables; however, I got a `json` exception: `A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported` which indicated that I had circular references.

Here is my code that gets around the issue using `DTO` objects, but is there a more cleaner way I can get around this issue as typing the, though it works, felt a bit wrong.

User:

```
namespace TestWebApplication.Database
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Dob { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Items> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Items:

```
namespace TestWebApplication.Database
{
    public class Items
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DtoItems:

```
namespace TestWebApplication.Database.DTOs
{
    public class DtoItems
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public DtoUser User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DtoUser:

```
namespace TestWebApplication.Database.DTOs
{
    public class DtoUser
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Dob { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TestController:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getitems")]
public ActionResult<List<Items>> GetItems()
{
    List<Items> items = _myContext.Items.Include(i => i.User).ToList();

    // DTOs
    List<DtoItems> dtoItems = new List<DtoItems>();

    foreach (var i in items)
    {
        var dtoItem = new DtoItems
        {
            Item = i.Item,
            Category = i.Category,
            Type = i.Type,
            User = new DtoUser
            {
                UserName = i.User.UserName,
                Dob = i.User.Dob,
                Location = i.User.Location
            }
        };

        dtoItems.Add(dtoItem);
    }

    return Ok(dtoItems);
}
```

The output from endpoint:

```
[
    {
        "item": "xxx",
        "category": "xxx",
        "type": "xxx",
        "user": {
            "userName": "xxx",
            "dob": "xxx",
            "location": "xx"
        }
    },
    {
        "item": "xxx",
        "category": "xxx",
        "type": "xxx",
        "user": {
            "userName": "xxx",
            "dob": "xxx",
            "location": "xxx"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Serialization problems should be solved there. EF Core won't help because it is not their concern (EF Core handles circular references without problem). See [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization)

Comment: @IvanStoev that's helpful.  I tried the `[JsonIgnore]` (`system.text.json`) attribute above the `ICollection<Items>` in the `User` class and its done the same job as the DTO code I wrote!  I'm worried about other issues like an infiniate amount of objects in memory if its in some kind of reference loop?

Comment: Let say you have 1 `User` with 5 `Items`. The `User` property of each of these 5 `Item`s points back to the **same** 1 `User`instance. So at the end you have just 6 objects, i.e. no additional amount of objects at all.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes more sense now.  One thing I tried experimenting with was first using the code from the *Related Data and Serialization* example in the `startup.cs` with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`, and what this did was give me an empty `items` array in the `user` object in the response.  So the `[JsonIgnore]` worked best for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Btw, don't get me wrong. Solving circular reference issue does not solve all serialization issues (for instance, if lazy loading is enabled). Using DTOs gives you much better control of what exactly is send back and forth than using entities directly, especially for returning data. For instance, if one and the same db context instance is used for several calls, the returned entity might contain related data even though it's not been requested explicitly.

Comment: Yes, there is much more I need to read and learn about this (e.g. lazy loading, etc.).  It's just experimental at the mo as I wanted to find out how to do a *one-to-many*.  Next will be maybe *code first* then a *many-to-many*.  That's exactly why I posted this as I read DTOs are the way forward in a real scenario (from Microsoft docs) and wondered if I had done it correctly or if there was a better way of doing what I done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, the use of a DTO is *the* correct way of dealing with this issue. The fact that your datamodel does not serialize well is trying to hint to you that you should not be serializing your datamodel from the API at all.

I think returning a DTO also solves further issues down the road (What if you want to return all properties of the UserModel except one, maybe it's a sensitive property you don't want to just return from your API, what if your UserModel in the DB gets more navigation properties that you don't want to return?).

There is really only two other ways of handling this.

- You can switch to Newtonsoft.Json which has support for handling reference loops and you can configure it one single line

Like so :

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

System.Text.Json does not have support for doing this (yet). Follow this Github Issue for more info : https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30820

- You use the JsonIgnore attribute to force non serialization of properties which will work but... It looks weird to have an EntityFramework model have JSON Serialization options on it...

So your best bet, stick with the DTO.

More info :

- https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/03/15/fixing-json-self-referencing-loop-exceptions/
- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30820
- https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReferenceLoopHandlingIgnore.htm

Comment: update: `System.Text.Json` can handle cycles as well now: JsonSerializer.Serialize(command, new JsonSerializerOptions { ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve })